# How to use jQuery to click a button at a given interval using chrome console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm trying to make a quick piece of code that I can plug into the chrome console to click a button at what would ideally be at 20 second intervals.I'm not an experienced programmer by any means, but I've tried a few things already.

It's worth noting that the page refreshes when the button is clicked.

This is the *closest* I can get to it working.

`function a(){$.click('[name="ad"]');setInterval(a,3000);`

But this only works once, and stops working when it refreshes. Is this even possible to do through the chrome console or do I need to use something else?

Comment: The page refresh is what's getting you.  As soon as the page navigates away/refreshes your interval is cleared.  Have you considered programmatically embedding the site in an `<iframe>`?  https://superuser.com/questions/436227/automatically-reload-page-in-chrome-without-plugin may prove helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use setInterval() like this, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

```
setInterval(
    function(){
        // do your operation
    },
3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

setInterval will work in Chrome. Try to nest your function directly in setInterval.

```
setInterval(function(){$('[name="ad"]').click()},3000);
```

Do you want to refresh the page once the button is clicked? If yes then no it will not work as page refresh will reset the timer as well.